# timeout on write() for linux pipe

Tags: c, pipe

How can I set timeout for write() on linux pipe ?

example code:

```
int fd_pipe = open("/run/some/pipe", O_RDWR);

// here i need to set timeout for 3 seconds somehow, if can't write, code will continue...
write(fd_pipe, something, strlen(something));

// continue executing..
```

thanks

Comment: The `write` call is much too low-level for that to be possible directly; there are a couple ways to work around this (eg. open the file in non-blocking mode or set an alarm signal). Alternately, you could try a higher-level call, which might be better anyway.

Comment: Open a fifo `O_READ` or `O_WRITE`, but never both, depending on the role you play with it.  If you write to a fifo and then read from it, you'll get back the data you wrote previously.  A fifo doesn't have socket semantics. And you won't get notified if the reader has closed a writing fifo, as you are another reader for that fifo.  If you want bidirectional communications, open a unix socket or use two fifos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as for network sockets you can use `select()` also on pipes to see, if a `write()` would block.

First, initialize the fdset and the timeout:

```
fd_set fds;
FD_ZERO(&fds);
FD_SET(fd_pipe, &fds);
struct timeval tv = { 3, 0 }; // 3 secs, 0 usecs
```

The following call waits at maximum 3 seconds (as specified in `tv`) for the pipe to become writable.

```
int st = select(fd_pipe+1, NULL, &fds, NULL, &tv);
if (st < 0) {
    // select threw an error
    perror("select");
else if (FD_ISSET(fd_pipe, &fds)) {
    int bytes = write(fd_pipe, something, strlen(something));
} else {
    // Writing not possible in 3 seconds, wait
}
```

You have of course to check the return value of the `write()` call (in both cases btw), because it might happen that *less* bytes than requested were written to the pipe.

Comment: Nope, this does not really work, even for sockets, the fact that the pipe is writable at best could mean that you can write *one* byte into it without blocking. And for even sockets it is well-known that for example Linux can report a socket as being readable, but then actually when you try to read from it then the kernel notices that the TCP packet had a checksum error and it needs to ask the other end to retransmit it...

Comment: The only way you can do it is select, then attempt to write in O_NONBLOCK mode and then retry select if it does not work.

Comment: In short, `select()` is fine. Just that the file descriptor(s) need to have `O_NONBLOCK` set for this to work as desired (can be done while `open()`ing or via `fcntl`).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I do not see how your comment is relevant here; Yes, perhaps only one byte can be written, but it will _not_ block. The return value of `write()` will be less than the passed buffer size, this has to be handled. I address this explicitly in the answer. The rest talks about reading and is completely irrelevant here.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala btw, TCP knows no mechanism to "ask for a retransmit", the packet is simply discarded. And fwiw, I believe that the paragraph about tcp checksums in the select manpage is inaccurate, this can never happen.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, TCP retransmissions ocurr in the sending side, when the timeout for the ACK elapses.  High level socket code simply behaves as if no data is in transit, so it has to block to wait for it.